# Feet pressure points for pronation detection in foot scan image

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing

Having problem in detecting feet pronation in foot scan image, I tried to mark pressure point based on threshold and able to get some results, but this technique failed in those images in which feet color is dark. Result of what I have tried is [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtgkD.jpg) but I want the final result looks like these [Feet Image Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT1Qc.jpg).
Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks

**Edit**
I have added the scan image of hand in which pressure points are circled and processed image supposed to detect only pressure point but it failed based on color of skin as I mentioned above. I'm applying color threshold. The image which in which detection failed is [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8hZN.jpg)

Comment: Can you add an example of an image that doesn't work properly?

Comment: @J.D. i  edited my question and added the image

Comment: Seems like you need actual _pressure sensor data_ instead of a photo...

Comment: @Nyerguds yes, you are right

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough color differences to do this easily. I tried by increasing contrast and converting to HSV colorspace ([info](http://learn.leighcotnoir.com/artspeak/elements-color/hue-value-saturation/) - [opencv](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html)), which makes selecting colors easier.

Result:

[image]

```
# load image
img = cv2.imread("hand.png")

#increase contrast
new_image = np.zeros(img.shape, img.dtype)
alpha = 4 # Simple contrast control
beta = -300    # Simple brightness control
for y in range(img.shape[0]):
    for x in range(img.shape[1]):
        for c in range(img.shape[2]):
            new_image[y,x,c] = np.clip(alpha*img[y,x,c] + beta, 0, 255)

# convert to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(new_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 
# set lower and upper color limits
lower_val = np.array([30,0,200])
upper_val = np.array([75,240,255])
# Threshold the HSV image 
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_val, upper_val)
# remove noise
kernel =  np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# select whole hand
# set lower and upper color limits
lower_val = np.array([0,0,100])
upper_val = np.array([179,255,255])
# Threshold the HSV image 
mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_val, upper_val)

# create a mask that has the whole hand, but not the prssure points
mask_combined = cv2.bitwise_xor(mask, mask2)
# Create a copy of the image
image = img.copy()
# Fill copy image with a blue-green-ish color
image[:] = (150, 150, 20)
# use the combined mask to color in upressured area's of the hand
res2 = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image, mask= mask_combined)
# Fill copy image with red color(set each pixel to red)
image[:] = (20, 20, 205)
# use the pressure mask to color in pressured area's
res = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image, mask= mask)
# combine colored images
final = dst = cv2.add(res2,res)
#show image
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.imshow("result", final)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("mask2", mask_combined)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Note: I cropped the image you provided, if you have the full image the result may improve by tweaking the colorlimits and the morphology - read about it [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html)

Comment: i really appreciate that for your help and i got your point but i want to want the whole feet or in your case hand image result in the form of color threshold the solution you have provided is pointing pressure points but remaining hand is not visible i want it to be visible clearly and just color difference on pressure points as i attached and image in my question

Comment: I extended the code to also mask out the hand and create a colored final result. Its not very pretty, but it's about as good as I can make it, without spending excessive time. Hopefully you can improve on this yourself. Good luck!